# fish シェルのコマンド入力時に env と alias 両方を使いたい

Tags: shell

alias be 'bundle exec' (もしくは be.fish を function 以下に作成) して設定していても, env と一緒に実行すると展開されない, 
`env RAILS_ENV=development be rails s` のコマンド内で be が `bundle exec` として認識されないと思うのですが,  これを fish でどうにか展開してくれる方法はあるのでしょうか？

`env RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails s` は勿論認識されるので, どうにかできないかなという気持ちです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: まぁ、`env RAILS_ENV=development fish -c 'be rails s'` などともできますけれども(無理矢理ですが)。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

env が外部コマンドのため、alias を解釈するのは無理です。
alias を解釈できるようにするには、env を function にするしかないと思います。

サンプルを作ってみました。

```
function env
    set -l i 1
    set -l loop 1
    while test $loop -ne 0 -a $i -le (count $argv)
        switch $argv[$i]
        case '*=*'
            set -l k (echo $argv[$i] | sed -e 's/=.*//')
            set -l v (echo $argv[$i] | sed -E 's/.*?=//')
            set --export $k $v
            set i (echo $i+1|bc)
        case '*'
            set loop 0
        end
    end

    if test $i -gt (count $argv)
        command env
    else
        eval $argv[$i..-1]
    end
end
```

ただし、このサンプルだといくつか制限がありまして、

- `env FOO=1 env | grep FOO` しても何も出ない。
- `env FOO=1 /bin/sh -c 'echo $FOO'` しても何も出ない。

です。

- `env FOO=1 ll`
- `env FOO=1 printenv FOO`

が問題ないので、質問に書かれている用途には使えると思います。